# I need to create a button that sends form information to email on button click event

Tags: asp.net, forms, email, button, submission

I'm new to everything programming and I'm in the process of creating a web form for my personal business that submits the form details to email on a button click. I've done a search, and I haven't quite been able to find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not sure what common protocol is when it comes to web form submission. I would rather not have the information on a database, as it is only temporary. Though it might be handy to have a name and phone number submitted to my database on button click.

The actual email doesn't need to be formatted well, I only need information from a few text boxes. I'm using TextBox1 - TextBox6, if that helps.

Thanks much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `System.Net.Mail` class to send emails in C#. The mail server settings are set up in your `web.config` file under the `system.net` `mailsettings` section. For example, email sent through a GMail account would use the following settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="[email_address_here]">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="[username]" password="[password]" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then, on the button click event, which you can access in the Events section of the Button's properties in Visual Studio, you would put the code to gather the form information and send the email, which would look something like:

```
//Initiate the mail client.
SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();

//You would probably get the to email from your form using TextBox1.Text or something similar, or use your own to email.
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("from_email", "to_email");

//Set the message properties, using your TextBox values to format the body of the email.
//You can use string format to insert multiple values into a string based on the order of {0}, {1}, {2} etc.
mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0}, thanks for emailing me.", TextBox2.Text);
mm.IsBodyHtml = true; //Or false if it isn't a HTML email.
mm.Subject = "Your Subject Here";

//Send the email.
mail.Send(mm);
```

You will also need to have the line `using System.Net.Mail;` at the top of your code file to use the `SMTPClient`.

Comment: Hmm make sure you have it in its own section in the `web.config` file. Try adding the `system.net` block just before `</configuration>` and see if that works. If not, you may have to post your whole `web.config` file for us to help further.

Comment: It's working great! Only have one problem. When the emails are being sent, I'm only receiving the first TextBox1.Text contents, anything that follows is blank. Here is the line of code i'm using:
"mm.Body = string.Format(TextBox6.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text);"

Comment: The way String.Format works is that you provide a string as the first parameter with index values like {0}, {1}, {2} etc. Then each value you pass in after that will be filled in in order, and the same index can be used multiple times. So you would need to do something like 

`mm.Body = string.Format("Here is a format {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text);`

Comment: You're a lifesaver! You helped me achieve exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working with?

In php, it would be something like this:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
... your form inputs
</form>
```

And then in post.php:

```
mail($_POST['email'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['body']);
```

Share the code you're working with and I can be more specific.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio ASP.NET, C#

Answer (score 0):

Any application server should be able to do this.  It sounds like you just need a simple script--PHP or Ruby would be practical--that processes the web request, extracts the data, and throws it into an email.  Maybe I'm missing part of the question, but if you literally mean you want to know the protocol, the answer is HTTP.

Comment: When I say I don't understand the protocol, I mean that I don't understand what the most common way to submit web forms. Web Forms are common around the internet, especially within the business realm.